# Can't bind path to image to the template - Angular

Tags: angular

My code is

```
<img *ngIf="photo" [src]="../../../../../../public/assets/images/2019-02-16T14:43:00.869Zpp1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
```

I'm trying to set the path to an image to the `src` of an `img` tag but I'm getting

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token . at column 1 in [../../../../../../public/assets/images/2019-02-16T14:43:00.869Zpp1.jpg] in ng:///ComponentsModule/SidebarComponent.html@5:8 ("
      <img
        *ngIf="photo"
        [ERROR ->][src]="../../../../../../public/assets/images/2019-02-16T14:43:00.869Zpp1.jpg"
        alt=""
     "): ng:///ComponentsModule/SidebarComponent.html@5:8
```

The complete idea is to make a GET requests to a user document that has a `userImgPath` property to the location where the image is. Then bind it to the `src=""` from an `img` tag. But i can't event do this first. I don't know whats wrong, thats the path to the image. The directory and the image already exist.

UPDATE:

After pzaenger answer I get this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to what @pzaenger mentioned, you need to have the image served from the correct place. If you have generated the app using angular-cli, you can have the image in `src/assets` folder and use in template like `[src]="'assets/photo.jpg'"`

Edit: You can modify the `angular.json or angular-cli.json` (if generated using angular-cli) to change the folders that are added to `assets` in the build.

Comment: This worked. It's like a workaround from that I wanted. I'll have to upload my images to the frontend directory then. They where in the backend ... Anyway this solves my problem for now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Escape the path using `''`:

```
<img *ngIf="photo" [src]="'../../../../../../public/assets/images/2019-02-16T14:43:00.869Zpp1.jpg'" alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Comment: I didn't get the error, now i have `2019-02-16T14:43:00.869Zpp1.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:4200/public/assets/images/2019-02-16T14:43:00.869Zpp1.jpg 404 (Not Found)` and the image is not displaying. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

use src insted [src] the second one is for string interpolation

examples:

```
<img src="assets/img/1.jpg" alt="image">

<img src='http://google.com/img/1.jpg' alt='image'>

<img [src]="imagePath" />

<img src={{imagePath}} />
```

Edit: 
If thats inside the application the path should be assets/images/imagename.jpg or ./assets/images/imagename.jpg

Comment: I get the same 404 error that I mentioned in the **update**. Thanks for your answer.